# How to add MaterialDesignInXaml icon to HamburgerMenu of mahapp?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to set as icon of the `HamburgerMenu` item, the icon available in the `PackIcon` of `MaterialDesignInXaml`, what I did so far:

```
 <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type materialDesign:PackIcon}">
            <Grid Height="48">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Kind}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" 
                           Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Label}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

I've defined a `MenuItemTemplate` in the `Grid` resources, using as `DataType` the `PackIcon` of materialDesign defined in this way:

```
xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
```

then, I'm trying to apply the icon on the Item:

```
 <Controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
            <Controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem  Glyph="?" Label="General">
                    <Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                        <Settings:view/>
                    </Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem.Tag>
                </Controls:HamburgerMenuGlyphItem>
```

I should get the `Kind` property instead of `Glyph`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want all items  to have this icon? just put the icon in your datatemplate. Or do you want to bind the icon basen on Kind property of your menuitem?

Comment: nope, each item need to have a custom icon that I define in the HamburgerMenuGlyphItem

Comment: oh. Then I don't get it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the wrong helper class `HamburgerMenuGlyphItem` where the `Glyph` property is a string and not an object.

If you want to use any additional object to display at the MenuItem, then you can use the `HamburgerMenuIconItem`. This has a property `Icon` with the type `object`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem}">
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"
          Height="48"
          Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- This ContentControl binds to the Icon property which contains a PackIconXYZ control -->
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Content="{Binding Icon}"
                        Focusable="False" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="16"
                   Text="{Binding Label}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can see this `DataTemplate` can display any object like a PackIcon. I used in this sample the [MahApps.Metro.IconPacks](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks) library which contains also such MarkupExtensions `{iconPacks:Material Kind=Home}`.

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="HamburgerMenuControl"
                        DisplayMode="CompactInline"
                        IsPaneOpen="True"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
                        OptionsItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
                        PaneForeground="White"
                        PaneBackground="#FF444444">

    <!--  Items  -->
    <controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
        <controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
            <controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{iconPacks:Material Kind=Home}"
                                               Label="Home">
                <controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                    <views:HomeView />
                </controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
            </controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>


            <controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{iconPacks:Material Kind=AccountCircle}"
                                               Label="Private">
                <controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                    <views:PrivateView />
                </controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
            </controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>


            <controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{iconPacks:Material Kind=Settings}"
                                               Label="Settings">
                <controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                    <views:SettingsView />
                </controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
            </controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>
        </controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>


    <!--  Options  -->
    <controls:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
        <controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
            <controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem Icon="{iconPacks:Material Kind=Help}" Label="About">
                <controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
                    <views:AboutView />
                </controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem.Tag>
            </controls:HamburgerMenuIconItem>
        </controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>

    <!--  Content template  -->
    <controls:HamburgerMenu.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controls:HamburgerMenuItem}">
            <Grid x:Name="TheContentGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="48" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF444444">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Header"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="24"
                               Foreground="White"
                               Text="{Binding Label}" />
                </Border>
                <ContentControl x:Name="TheContent"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Content="{Binding Tag}"
                                Focusable="False"
                                Foreground="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu.ContentTemplate>

</controls:HamburgerMenu>
```

This sample can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/punker76/code-samples/tree/master/MahAppsMetroHamburgerMenu/HamburgerMenuApp.V3).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank punker, could you please check also this question when you have time:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290526/accentcolormenudata-cannot-locate-color-resource